# Adjusting ticks to histogram ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need the ticks on x axis to go over next integer. Something like this

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg))+
  geom_histogram( )+
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(11,13,15,17,19,21))
```

I want to avoid manually inputting the breaks. So I tried

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg))+
  geom_histogram( )+
scale_x_continuous(breaks = noquote(paste(seq(11,21,2))))
```

However, it gives an error. I do not understand why it does that since both `c(11,13,15,17,19,21)` and `noquote(paste(seq(11,21,2)))` have the same output.

My questions then are: why I have different results and what can I do to avoid the manual input if my code can not work at all for some reason.

Comment: They are not remotely the same output. Run `str()` on both. Never assume that because something looks the same when _printed_ at the console that it actually has the same structure.

Comment: Thanks joran. I realized it after posting the question. And your comment confirmed it. I tried 'as.numeric' for my second alternative and it worked

Comment: Rather than `as.numeric(noquote(paste(seq(11, 21, 2))))`, you could just do `seq(11, 21, 2)`. `seq` outputs a numeric, `paste` converts it to character, `noquote` keeps it character but prints without quotes, and `as.numeric` converts it back to numeric. It's a great big circle.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks. This was my starting point. As I missed, apparently, a bracket, it did not work, so I started my big circle.